# Why eventListener in JavaScript not displaying?

Tags: javascript, events

I have been struggling for hours with a simple addEventListener and I really don't understand why.

Find attached my JS code. I am trying to create a cart. I store in a localstorage the products I want to buy. Then I display it on a test page to see if my code was working.

I add a class to each line of the array using `i` variable.

Then I try to do a simple alert when I click on the link I created with the class. The goal is then to add a link to remove this article from the cart.

I get no error, but the alert does not display.

Plus, when I do

```
alert(querySelector('.article' + i + '').innerHTML);
```

it works perfectly, but with the code below it does not :

```js
let url = window.location.search;
let searchUrl = new URLSearchParams(url);

if (searchUrl.has("produit")) {

  //Requête fetch
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cameras')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(produit) {
      produit.forEach(element => {

        // Récupération url, conversion string et mise en forme pour recherche
        let urlProduit = String(searchUrl.getAll("produit"));
        urlProduit = urlProduit.replace("-", " ");

        //Affichage du produit
        if (urlProduit == element.name) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<a href="#" class="lienProduit">' + element.name + '</a>';
          document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<p>' + element.description + '</p>';
          document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<p>' + element.price + '</p>';
          document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<a href="" id="ajoutPanier"> Ajouter au panier </a>';

          // Gestion du panier
          document.getElementById('ajoutPanier').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (localStorage.getItem("panier") == null) {
              let panier = {};
              panier.produits = [];
              localStorage.setItem('panier', JSON.stringify(panier));
              alert("Panier créé");
            } else {
              let panier = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("panier"));

              panier.produits.push(element);

              localStorage.setItem("panier", JSON.stringify(panier));
              alert("Ajouté au panier");
            }
          });
        }
      })
    })
}

//Affichage du panier
if (!localStorage.getItem("panier")) {
  document.getElementById('panier').innerHTML += '<p> Votre panier est vide</p>';
}
else {

  //Vider le panier
  document.querySelector('#panier h2').innerHTML += ' (<a href="#" class="viderPanier">Vider</a>) ';
  document.querySelector('.viderPanier').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("Panier vidé");
  });

  let i=0;
  let panier = localStorage.getItem("panier");
  panier = JSON.parse(panier);
  console.log(panier); // A supprimer
  panier.produits.forEach(element => {
  document.getElementById('panier').innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + element.name + '</strong> - ' + element.price + ' € - <a href="" class="article' + i + '"> Retirer du panier </a> - Position' + i + ' </p>';
  document.querySelector('.article' + i + '').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("ok");
    alert("ok");
    })
    i++;
  })




  document.getElementById('panier').innerHTML += '<a href="">Passer la commande</a>';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page produit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
<a href="index.html">Retour à l'acceuil</a><br>
  <h2>Votre produit</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="panier">
      <h2>Votre panier</h2>

    </div>
    <script src="produit.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just started JavaScript and eventListener perfectly worked so far. I know it is not the best solution for what I want to create, I am open to tips from you guys.

Comment: you must be getting some console error. isn't it ? if not how do you read `i`'s value ?

Comment: Your code sample is not instantiating i. Are you sure that it's valid? Also the second argument passed into the callback in foreach is the index. Maybe you should use that instead of i.

Comment: I did not put the entire code. i is defined above this code :) I get no error in console

Comment: this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-chandrasekhar-ldpf2?file=/src/index.js) works. Your problem is somewhere else

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the code you have provided to a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552). If you [edit] your question, you can edit your snippet (there is a link below the snippet). Please add just enough HTML and code (e.g., what is in `panier`) so that others can run the code and see what's wrong. Since your question does not seem to revolve around the use of `localStorage`, I'd just remove that.

Comment: Thank you, SO is new to me. I just added the complet js code and the html linked page